# Ubuntu 16.04 phpmyadmin is not working

Tags: phpmyadmin

i installed phpmyadmin in my ubuntu 16.04  OS . i can't access to the phpmyadmin.
i installed 
apache2 , mysql , php7.0
[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like your system is supported php, have you created a test file in your website root with `<?php phpinfo() ?>` to test it?

Comment: Check your apache error log located at /var/log/apache2/error.log , You may have some missing php extention.